# How do I get the values in PROGRAM 2 to apply to printing in the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, console

Okay so I technically have everything working in the program, but I need to permanently change the values of the array that I create in PROGRAM 2 and add -blip and -clang. What do I call upon to change the values so that I can call them to the console in PROGRAM 3? I can't have anything in the body so innerHTML and document.write are out of the question(which sucks). Problem area is marked with a comment on line 37 to make it easier to find.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 1 – Michael Fiorello</title>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
do {
    //MAIN MENU

    var input = prompt("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or exit.");
    {
//PROGRAM 1-Enter the string to be converted to robot speak
    if (input === "1")
        do {
            var one = prompt ("Please enter a string.");
                {
                    if (one === "") 
                        { 
                            console.warn("You need to enter something");
                        }
                }

        } while (one === "")//keep repeating program 1 until something is entered, aka cannot be blank.

//PROGRAM 2-Convert the string into robot speak
    else if (input === "2")
        {
          if (one == null) {
                                console.warn ("You need to first enter a String");
                           }
            else 
                {
                    console.log ("String Converted")
                        var res = one.split(" ");
                            for(i = 0; i<res.length; i++)
                             if(res[i].length >= 5)
//What do I do here to change the value of entered strings in the array, rather than just write it out?
                                        {
                                    document.write(res[i]+"-blip ");
                                        }
                                else
                                        {
                                    document.write(res[i]+"-clang ");
                                        }
                  }

         }
    //Program 3 Robot Language version of the string will appear in the console
    else if (input === "3")
        {
            var output = res.join(" ");
                alert ("AWESOME!"); 
                console.log (output);
                    }
                        else if (input == null|| input.toLowerCase() == "exit")
                    {
                        alert ("Thanks for using the ROBOT Language Converter!");
                    }
    else 
        {
            alert ("Nope");
            console.warn("You need to enter something");
        }
    }
    } while(input.toLowerCase() != "exit");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any arrays in the code you've posted. There's also a handful of syntax errors here. Go [read up on the basics of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) before you try to tackle arrays.

Comment: Updated problem

Comment: what is the problem actually?

Comment: I need to change the values of the string entered in PROGRAM 2. I'm converting it into an array so that I can check the length of each word entered, but I also need to add the -blip and -clang to it by changing the strings, which I then have to call to the console in PROGRAM 3. We are required to have nothing in the body so I can't use "document.write" or "element.innerHTML" that I was attempting. So what should I use to permanently change the values of the strings in the array?

Comment: Simply put. How do I change the value of the string to be called upon rather than simply writing the string out on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple that I feel like an idiot. All I had to do was change the document.write lines to

```
res[i] = (res[i]+"-blip ");
```

and it changes the values to what I need.